How do I create a "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" or "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY" column using the pgAdmin GUI in PostgreSQL?
I'm trying to figure out how I can add a GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY or GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY without needing to write SQL code.
I know I'm able to add them using code like this:
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD COLUMN id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;

or
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD COLUMN id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;


But is there perhaps a way to do it using the pgAdmin GUI tool instead of writing SQL as I would much rather prefer being able to do it using the GUI?
It seems like something that should be there, but I just can't find it. I tried searching on Google as well, but couldn't find anything useful with my searches.

How are you going to put the GUI interaction to create the identity under source control? I think you still need the DDL because that can be backed up and kept in source control.

Just as I was about to give up and finally post this question, I discovered the answer. So I'll post the answer here for others that are struggling to find it also.

Right-click on your table and go to Properties..., then under the Columns tab, you'll be able to click on the Edit row button icon to find it:

From here you can then set your column to be "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" or "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY".
